# Java open source project(wihout tests) for testing

Tags: java, open-source

I am looking for a java open-source project that is multithreaded, has database persisting and a web part and that doesn't contain any unit tests. It also mustn't be bigger than 100 classes. I want to write the tests for such a program.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question would be more relevant here:
[stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 3):

You can find open source projects source at below locations -

1. [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/open-source/projects)
2. [Java forge](http://www.javaforge.com/project/11)
3. [code google](http://code.google.com) (for small projects)

Comment: The idea is if someone knows of such a project. I know all those sites, and am currently searching in them :)

Comment: So you want project definition ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find opesource projects  at:

- [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/%E2%80%8E)
- [github](https://github.com/%E2%80%8E)